# strlen EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Xcode - c

Tags: c, xcode5

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char x[256];
    strcpy(x, "Gonzo!");
    printf(strlen(x));
}
```

I'm not sure that I am coding this correctly. I want to know the string length of **x**.

I am using XCode 5+ and I get the error:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is a `const char*`, which specifies the format. The posted code passes in `6` as the starting memory location for the `char*` which is incorrect and is causing the error. Use:

```
printf("%d\n", strlen(x));
```

See the linked `printf()` reference documentation.

Comment: Ahh, I did not indeed remember the %d. Thanks!